# Apache SSL server not starting

Tags: server, apache2

I have installed Apache 2.0.58 together with PHP 5.1.4. When I start the server using `./apachectl start`, I manage to get the server running to serve "HTTP" pages as well as "PHP" pages, but when I try to start SSL for HTTPS using `./apachectl startssl`, I get the error below:

```
(125)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:54912
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

For reference, I hosted my HTTPS page on port 54912, and while in `httpd.conf` it already has the `Listen 54912` directive, I also changed the file `ssl.conf` to `Listen 54912` from the default `Listen 443`.

Any idea how I can get my server to run and serve HTTPS?

Comment: Is the server already running as a service? Did you try to `sudo service apache2 stop`?

Answer (score 1):

Got the server running! :)

The problem is because there are 2 **Listen 54912** inside config. So by changing the file **httpd.conf** to **Listen 14912** and retaining the file **ssl.conf** to **Listen 54912**, I can now run **apachectl startssl** and after entering the password, the server is up and running!

Special thanks to Tim Yencken for the help. (Dunno if he's here or not).